# how to download an imported style sheet from a website?

Tags: css, web

I often need to use some styles from a website but i cant find those style sheets since it is linked using an import function. can anyone say how to download/view those imported style sheets.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do. Depending on which browser you use you can activate developer tools in the settings. You can then right klick on a part of the website you want to have the styles from and often times it says something like "inspect element" in the menu. You will then be able to view the styles that are applied to this specific element or webpage and you will also be able to copy those to the clipboard.

I actually hope this will be of help to you.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/